# Click event in sencha Ext.List component

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I created List using sencha touch 2.

```
var aroundList = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    itemCls : 'my-dataview-item',
    id : 'aroundMeList',
    itemTpl : '<div><img style="padding:1px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:{trustColor}" src="' + localStorage.httpServerPrefix + '{imageURI}"/><span id="name">{fullname}</span><span id="time">{time}</span><p id="msg">{text}<span id="count">&nbsp;{replyCount}&nbsp;</span></p><p id="dist">&nbsp;< '+localStorage.radius+''+localStorage.unit+' '+'&nbsp;</p></div>',
    store : aroundStore,
    listeners : {
        select : {
            fn : this.onMessageClickedInAround,
            scope : this
        }
    }
});
```

I am getting output like this (Not exactly but, something like this)

[image]

when user clicks first row or first item in the List, i am calling onMessageClickedInAround method (this method is  for showing messages from that user), you can see the above code.

**now i have a requirement that, when the user clicks any picture in the List, i need to show that corresponding Profile page (that is, one user can see others profile by clicking image in the List)**, is there any way i can do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list is populating by a data source, sencha touch will pass the corresponding record to your itemTap listeners. You can do that as something like following.

```
    listeners : {
        itemtap: function (list, index, item, record) {
            // Show next view based on current record
        }
    }
```

If you only want to do it on image tap you can check for the event in that listener.

```
    listeners : {
        itemtap: function (list, index, item, record, senchaEvent) {
            if (senchaEvent.event.target.nodeName === 'img') {
                // Show next view
            }
        }
    }
```

You can give a class to `<img>` and check for that as well.

Comment: senchaEvent.event.target.nodeName returns "IMG"

Answer (score 4):

You should use event delegation for this

*Update*

```
var aroundList = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    // rest of your cfg
    listeners : {
        // other listeners
        tap: {
            fn: yourHandler,
            element: 'element',
            delegate: 'img'
        }
    }
});
```

As stated the following is obsolete

```
var aroundList = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    // rest of your cfg
    listeners : {
        // other listeners
        el: {
            tap: yourHandler,
            delegate: 'img'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer and i think your answer is old, as per the following [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?176239-HOWTO-Adding-Event-Listeners-to-Component-Elements). is it?

Comment: @Viswa Well, you are right. I have missed that. None the less should you use delegate. I didn't mentioned that cause the word sound sort of cool ;)

Comment: ok, i need to call profile function if the user taps img and messageSelect function if the user taps any item other than image.. how can i do that using your example..

Comment: am i need to have two events within listener?

Comment: @sra i have one doubt. if i use delegate, how to get taped record ?